# hibernate secondary table with one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate

One of our goals is to follow the object oriented design and come up with business objects and then take the trouble to create the appropriate mappings for the persistence. It seems to work for most part, but I am getting stuck in the following scenario:

### Rule table

RuleId (PK),
name,
Desc,
Type

### RuleDetail table

RuleDetailId (PK),
RuleId (FK),
Type,
StartDate,
EndDate
....10 other columns

The important thing here is that these objects follow an inheritence relationship (governed by Type) and one to many between the Rule and RuleDetail.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RULE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "TYPE",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER
)
@SecondaryTable(name="RULE_DETAIL", pkJoinColumns={
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="RULEID")})
public abstract class RuleBO extends BaseBO<Long> implements IRuleBO {
    @Id @Column(name = "RULEID")    
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "desc")
    private String desc;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name= "TYPE")
    private RuleType type;

    @Embedded
    @Column(table="RULE_DETAIL")
    private Effectivity effectivity;

    @Column(name="AMOUNT", table="RULE_DETAIL")
    private Double Amt; 
    @Column(name="PERCENTAGE", table="RULE_DETAIL")
    private Double percentage;

    @Column(name="PERCENTAGEOF", table="RULE_DETAIL")
    private Integer percentageOf;

    ......specify all the remaining columns
}
```

I am struggling to come up with where to specify the OneToMany relationship. Should I specify for all the secondary table columns or just the foreign key column? I am not even sure if this approach is going to work. 
When I create multiple BOs and use the join criteria, it works as expected, but I was given the challenge to make it work with just one BO and am struggling to make it work. Can someone please guide me in the right direction? At a basic level, secondary table seems straight forward, but I dont know if I am over complicating the solution. I am not sure if I can specify the ID on the secondary table as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would not join across the tables in Hibernate like that as you're forcing a 1:1 as the parent class RuleBO has precisely one instance of "Amount", "Percentage" and "percentageOf" which is in the child table (which you want to be 1:n).

Instead, create a RuleDetail class and map it back onto the RuleBO class using the @OneToMany annotation.

Also, don't abbreviate variables and be consistent in your use of camelCase (i.e. use "amount" not "Amt")

```
private List<RuleDetailBO> ruleDetails;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ruleid")
public List<RuleDetailBO> getRuleDetails() {
    return ruleDetails;
}
```

Comment: I got it to work with multiple classes. Is there a way to make it work with just one class? I even tried the approach of flipping so I would make the primary table RULEDETAIL and the secondary table Rule, but hibernate was complaining that the secondary table joinColumn cannot reference a non primary key.

Comment: Think about it logically, you have something that is in the multiple, you will need a collection, you can't sensibly map via a single class.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. But what about the approach of creating a BO that has all the details. That is actually our business object. My original approach was creating the class with the RuleDetail, but use name, description as the columns from the secondary table (Rule). It did not work because of Hibernate complaining about the join column cannot reference a non primary key. Is there a work around for that?

Comment: As I understand it, your RuleBO is composed of multiple RuleDetails. If it has multiple RuleDetail in the database for each RuleBO, then this is just how RDBMS's are supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, we want to restructure our business object to be truly object oriented. So, the RuleDetail is more or less our BO, but will also include name, description from the Rule table. The RuleDetailBO should be mapped to both Rule and RuleDetail tables. You can ignore the original posted question as I see the problem with that approach. My question is  there a way to map the Rule as a secondary table (name and desc columns)?